# Azure Private Link - DNS Zone Setup

Tags: azure, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns-zone

I have applications running in two separate VNETs (in same subscription) that need to connect to a third party DB service using Private Link. I have created two private end points specific to each VNET however not sure how to setup the Private DNS Zone. Since the DNS Zone is global, how do I reference the record referencing the db DNS entry?  While adding this record , it requires IP for the private end point. In my case I have two private end points.

Appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two separate, non-peered/connected VNets, you would create two separate private DNS Zones and [link them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-virtual-network-links) with the respective VNet (each with only one VNet). You would not use public (global) DNS zones, as you don't want to resolve them outside of your private networks.

If two private DNS zones provide the same domain, they need to be in different resource groups.

Maybe the [hub and spoke network architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?tabs=cli) is interesting for you, if you need to scale for many applications.

Comment: can we have multiple VNets connect to the same Private DNS Zone?

Comment: @Faizal you can link multiple vnets to one private DNS zone

Comment: I created the Private DNS Zone and linked both VNETs and added A type record with both private IPs. However when I access the private link it is throwing timeout error , issue seems to be it's not connecting to the private IP specific to the VNET (it' s swapping). Any thoughts? Thanks